# Is the battery in the new Macbook (the one with USB-C) replaceable?

Tags: macbook-pro

It seems that the new battery is glued into the computer. Does this mean that it can't be replaced, or has Apple somehow figured out a way to remove the glue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery in the new MacBook is replaceable but Apple recommends that you bring it to them for servicing and replacement, if necessary.  [Here's what Apple says about the battery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204054):

> MacBook, MacBook Air, and MacBook Pro computers with built-in batteries should only have their batteries replaced by an [Apple Authorized Service Provider](https://locate.apple.com/) or [Apple Retail Store](http://www.apple.com/retail/). Attempting to replace a built-in battery yourself could damage your equipment, and such damage is not covered by warranty.
>
> These Mac notebooks have built-in batteries:
>
> - MacBook (13-inch, Late 2009) and later
> - All MacBook Air computers
> - All MacBook Pro computers with Retina display
> - MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2009) and later; MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2009) and later